# Google Cloud Storage free trial quota details

Tags: google-cloud-storage

- Is there a possibility to set a quota (usage limit) for Google Cloud Storage while I am in the free trial quota? Otherwise I have unlimited risk until I notice it and set the quotas, when the free trial quota ends.

  (I can set quotas on the quotas tab of my google api console for activated apis like Prediction API.)
- "Google Cloud Storage offers a free trial quota until December 31, 2012".
  Will there be any free trial quota afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage does not implement usage limits on the XML API or for HTTP reads of public objects. The JSON API has a daily cap ("Courtesy limit") listed in the Google API Console -> Services (https://code.google.com/apis/console/). You can request a change to that cap via the link next to it, but it won't affect the other two options for accessing the data.

The Free Trial Quota is independent of this, it makes the initial usage each month free of charge. Details here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/pricingandterms

Comment: Also, the free trial was extended this week. The pricing page now reads: "Google Cloud Storage offers a free trial quota until June 30, 2013." https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/pricingandterms